# $T: \mathbb{C}_{2020}[x]\to \mathbb{C}_{2020}[x]$, $\sum_{i=0}^{2020}a_ix^i \mapsto \sum_{i=0}^{2020}a_i(x-1)^i$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form

$T: \mathbb{C}_{2020}[x]\to \mathbb{C}_{2020}[x]$

$\sum_{i=0}^{2020}a_ix^i \mapsto  \sum_{i=0}^{2020}a_i(x-1)^i$

I have to find the presentation matrix of $T$ in order to find Jordan form.

I tried to find it by the standard basis of $\mathbb{C}_{2020}[x]$ but I am little confused about the $\sum_{i=0}^{2020}a_i(x_i-1)^i.$

I cant present the polynomials with the basis standard.

Help please?

Comment: Binomial theorem tells you how to expand each term. Then you have to collect by degree. You will have an easier time if you try first to look at the case of polynomials of degree 3 or 4.

Comment: What is $\mathbb C_{2020}[x]$?

Comment: @KentaS the polynomials of degree 2020 or less.

Comment: Just plug in the standard basis into $T$, i.e. consider the cases when $a_j=1$ for one index $j$ and all other $a_k=0$. (Note that using $i$ as index over $\Bbb C$ is a bit unlucky.)

Comment: $(x-1)^j=x^j-jx^{j-1}+\frac{j(j-1)}{2!}x^{j-2}\cdots -\frac{j(j-1)\cdots(j-k)}{k!}x^{j-k}+\frac{j(j-1)\cdots(j-k+1)}{(k+1)!} x^{j-(k+1)}$ , is it correct ? the presetation matirx is the coefficients of x ?

Comment: @erez that's true for one term, but you're going to get more contributions from the other terms you will expand. So you're going to be summing these coefficients. There is a pattern to their summation that you might know, or that you might be able to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to put it into Jordan form without calculation.

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $T$ and $f \in \Bbb C_n[x]$ be an eigenvector for $\lambda$, where $n = 2020$. That is, $T(f) = \lambda f$, i.e. $f(x - 1) = \lambda f$.

By comparing the leading coefficient, we see that $\lambda$ must be equal to $1$. Moreover, $f(x) = f(x - 1)$ can only happen when $f$ is a constant polynomial, by e.g. arguing with the sum of all roots of $f$.

Thus $T$ has only one eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ and the space of eigenvectors for $\lambda = 1$ is one dimensional. Therefore the Jordan form has only one block, with diagonal and subdiagonal entries equal to $1$ and other entries equal to $0$.

Comment: "By comparing the leading coefficient, we see that λ must be equal to 1" - since $(x-1)^i=\boldsymbol 1 \cdot x^i +\cdots$ ?

Comment: Leading coefficient means the highest degree nonzero coefficient.

Comment: By the way , there is a way to find a matrix P such that $P^-1AP=J$ without finding the presentation matrix ?

Comment: This would be equivalent to finding polynomials $f_0, f_1, \dots, f_n$ such that $f_i(x - 1) - f_i(x) = f_{i - 1}(x)$. Basically you can start with any $f_n$ of degree $n$ and work downwards to get all the $f_i$, but there is a good choice: $f_n(x) = \binom x n = \frac{x(x-1)\cdots(x - n + 1)}{n!}$. I'll leave the details to you.

Comment: I think it's easier to show that the only eigenvectors are constant functions by assuming $deg \ge 1$ and then examining the coefficient of the ($deg -1$) term.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** As mentioned in the comments, we can compute the coefficients of the matrix representation $[T]$ of $T$ with respect to the standard basis $(1,x,\ldots,x^{2020})$ of $\Bbb C_{2020}[x]$ by expanding using the Binomial Theorem:
$$T(x^j) = (x - 1)^j = x^j + {j \choose 1}(-1)^1 x^{j - 1} + \cdots = x^j - j x^{j - 1} + \cdots .$$
In particular, $T(x^j)$ is the sum of $x^j$ and a linear combination of (strictly) smaller powers of $x$.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain their objection to what seems to me like a routine answer?